# Spree: heroku deploy error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I keep getting following:

```
remote:        Gem::InstallError: spree_core requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.
remote:        An error occurred while installing spree_core (3.0.4), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install spree_core -v '3.0.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

when I run

```
gem install spree_code -v '3.0.4'
```

it is successful and afterwards when I run git push heroku master again I get the exact same error.

```
rbenv versions
```

shows following:

```
2.2.2 (set by /Users/Martijn/.rbenv/version)
```

Comment: code you please paste here your gem file?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku needs the ruby version defined in the Gemfile, like:
`ruby "2.2.1"`. More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions.